TypeError at /api/register-application/
I was trying to deploy my system, as everything was working easily on localhost:8000 but when i deploy same code on the server then with the domainname api i cannot post any data with same function worked in localhost:8000.
the error is
TypeError at /api/register-application/
unhashable type: 'set'
Request Method: POST
enter image description here
I want a solution to fix this issue.

Can you please share the code?

did you post your data with a csrf_token and enable csrf settings in settings.py?
